# Errors while inserting elements in MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, database

I'm trying to insert a large number of elements in a MongoDB collection using pymongo. The script I wrote inserts 35816 elements in the db and then it starts giving me the following error:

```
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pymongo\helpers.py", line 301, 
    in _check_write_command_response
        raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error) 
pymongo.errors.WriteError: assertion C:\data\mci\src\src\mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h:204
```

And in mongod.exe's log there is also a `code:8` after that.

I don't quite understand what the problem is: i'm sure there are no key conflicts because I tried to print the failed elements and I searched for their `_id`s in the elements that are already present in the db.

Comment: I'd suggest do proper exception handling around code block inserting documents in MongoDB. Log if any error and see what's going on. Without any context, it's next to impossible to suggest anything constructive.

Comment: @Saleem yeah, in the meantime I may have found the codes descriptions and code:8 means "Unkown error".... https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/50dc6dbe394c42d03659aa3410954f1e3ff46740/src/mongo/base/error_codes.err#L12

Comment: @Saleem also, exception handling does not give me any other useful info: the only thing that it prints is `assertion C:\data\mci\src\src\mongo/util/concurrency/rwlock.h:204`

Comment: hmm, may I know your MongoDB server version and pymongo version?

Comment: Though it doesn't mater, but how are you inserting documents? are you using insert_many?

Comment: @Saleem MongoDB version : 3.2.3; Pymongo 3.2; I tried both with insert_one and with insert_many. In both cases the number of inserted docs is the same and the failing docs are also the same, but there is nothing wrong with them: their syntax is exactly the same of the other ones.

Comment: In case of insert many you can bundle multiple documents together and is bit permanent. anyway check your mongodb log. you may have some clue there. Honestly, I haven't witness such error.

Comment: @Saleem ok, thank you anyway!